# Meteor fibers/future.js Push is not defined

Tags: ios, reactjs, meteor, html-framework-7, fibers

I am attempting to run an old meteor app that is giving me some trouble. Below is the error I receive when using the command:

`meteor --settings settings-development.json run ios`

Example of what my settings-development.json looks like:

```
{
    "public": {
        "mixpanel": {
            "token": "token"
        },
        "fcm": {
            "senderID": 111111111111
        }
    },
    "wpdb": {
        "host": "localhost",
        "name": "wordpress_dev",
        "user": "root",
        "pass": ""
    },
    "fcm": {
        "serverKey": "abc_de123_..."
    },
    "push_pw": "abc123"
}
```

What my package.json looks like:

```
{
  "name": "food",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "meteor run",
    "test": "meteor test --once --driver-package meteortesting:mocha"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.10.2",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.2.0",
    "@gouch/to-title-case": "^2.2.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.7",
    "fibers": "^5.0.3",
    "framework7": "^3.6.5",
    "framework7-react": "^3.6.5",
    "history": "^4.7.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "^0.4.1",
    "mixpanel-browser": "^2.38.0",
    "mysql": "^2.16.0",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "react-router": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6"
  }
}
```

The error that I receive:

```
W20230815-10:54:07.782(-4)? (STDERR) /Users/User/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.2.13.0.d0os0r.uhfej++os.osx.arm64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.arm64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280
W20230815-10:54:07.789(-4)? (STDERR)                                            throw(ex);
W20230815-10:54:07.790(-4)? (STDERR)                                            ^
W20230815-10:54:07.790(-4)? (STDERR)          
W20230815-10:54:07.790(-4)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: Push is not defined
W20230815-10:54:07.790(-4)? (STDERR)     at imports/startup/both/index.js:7:2
W20230815-10:54:07.790(-4)? (STDERR)     at packages/meteor.js:365:18
W20230815-10:54:07.790(-4)? (STDERR)     at Function.time (/Users/User
/Desktop/food/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/profile.js:251:30)
W20230815-10:54:07.790(-4)? (STDERR)     at /Users/User/Desktop/food/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:398:15
W20230815-10:54:07.791(-4)? (STDERR)     at /Users/User/Desktop/food/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:440:7
W20230815-10:54:07.791(-4)? (STDERR)     at Function.run (/Users/User/Desktop/food/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/profile.js:256:14)
W20230815-10:54:07.791(-4)? (STDERR)     at /Users/User/Desktop/food/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:438:13
%% Adding xcodebuildArg: [ '-UseModernBuildSystem=0' ]
%% Adding xcodebuildArg: [ '-quiet' ]         
2023-08-15 10:54:08.654 xcodebuild[123:123] DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState: DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState_Disabled set via user default (DVTEnableCoreDevice=disabled)
--- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:123, OS:16.4, name:iPhone 14 Pro Max }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:123, OS:16.4, name:iPhone 14 Pro Max }
```

My current version of Meteor is 2.13, Node is 14.18.0, and npm is 9.5.1.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

I am just hoping to launch the application to a usable state so that the app can be updated enough for a release to the app store. I have tried updating several packages. I have tried recloning and going through the dev environment set up many times.